# Can you use a stave with the use magic device skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, skills

Is it possible to use a stave with Use Magic Device? If it's possible, what is do you use as caster level and casting stat modifier for the spells, since it normally uses the casting stat modifier and caster level of the user?

Answer (score 2):

## A creature can employ the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device/) to activate a magic [staff](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves/)

The following is one of the uses of the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device/):

> ***Use a*** Wand, **Staff**, or Other Spell Trigger Item: Normally, to use a wand, you must have the wand’s spell on your class spell list. This use of the skill allows you to use a wand as if you had a particular spell on your class spell list. Failing the roll does not expend a charge.

(Emphasis mine.) This Use Magic Device skill use's Difficulty Class is 20. By default, the spell from the magic staff will be cast at the staff's listed caster level using the normal saving throw DCs appropriate to the spell (e.g. a creature that makes a Use Magic Device skill check to activate a [*staff of the woodlands*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves/staff-of-the-woodlands/) sees the staff's [*charm animal*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-animal/) effect generated at a caster level of 13 with a likely saving throw DC of 14; that is, DC 10 base +1 for spell's level +3 for the minimum ability score of 17 necessary to cast the *staff*'s highest level spell).

A generous GM may allow a second Use Magic Device skill check to emulate the class feature spells of a casting class that has on its spell list the spell stored in the staff, making "your effective level in the emulated class [equal to] your Use Magic Device check result minus 20." Likewise, the GM may allow a further Use Magic Device skill check to emulate an ability score, making "[y]our effective ability score [equal to] your Use Magic Device check result minus 15"; note that typically such a check is only demanded when attempting to use a magic scroll, making this particular use a *very* nonstandard use of the skill. Even if allowed, these options are, obviously, only attractive to creatures with high Use Magic Device skill modifiers. Most should be satisfied with merely activating the magic staff.

Comment: thanks, but do i need to make the checks to emulate an ability score/caster level each time i umd the staff, or do i do it just one time and it's works each time i umd the staff ? If not, can i do all the checks in one action ?

Comment: If the GM's allows Use Magic Device skill checks to emulate a class feature and emulate an ability score when making a check to activate the staff, I'd expect all three checks to be needed each time an attempt was made to activate the staff (rather than the normal lone check needed to activate the staff), *but*, as the first two checks *are* nonstandard uses of the skill, you'll have to ask the GM. However, all three checks should be *not an action*, made when the bearer attempts to activate the staff.